# DSC to create multiple apppools

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to create multiple app pools using DSC. If I try to make the $AppPoolName accept an array I get the error:

Exception calling "ValidateInstanceText" with "1" argument(s): "Convert property 'Name' value from type 'STRING[]' to type 'STRING' failed. It does work if I do the below and only accept one app pool

```
Configuration Sample_xWebAppPool
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]
        $AppPoolName,

        [ValidateSet("Started", "Stopped")]
        [string]
        $state="Started",

        [String[]]
        $NodeName = 'localhost'
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xWebAdministration

    Node $NodeName
    {
        xWebAppPool $AppPoolName
        {
            Name                           = $AppPoolName
            Ensure                         = 'Present'
            State                          = $state
            autoStart                      = $true
            idleTimeout                    = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 20).ToString()  
            restartPrivateMemoryLimit      = 700000
            logEventOnRecycle              = 'Time,Memory,PrivateMemory'
        }
    }
}
Sample_xWebAppPool -NodeName "server" -state started -AppPoolName "AppPool1"
```

I want to be able to do this sort of thing:

```
Sample_xWebAppPool -NodeName "server" -state started -AppPoolName "AppPool1","AppPool2","AppPool3"
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way or best way of doing this.

Comment: Why is the `$NodeName` parameter a string array and the `$AppPoolName` parameter a single string? It seems you want the opposite if you're trying to add multiple AppPools. The error message indicates `xWebAppPool` doesn't take an array in the `Name` parameter.  Use a Foreach loop and add each AppPool, one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I make the apppoolname an array I get an error saying it cannot accept multiple values. the nodename is an array in case I want to create multiple mof files for different computers. I guess I will have to use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this works:

```
Configuration Sample_xWebAppPool
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String[]]
        $AppPoolName,

        [ValidateSet("Started", "Stopped")]
        [string]
        $state="Started",

        [String[]]
        $NodeName = 'localhost'
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xWebAdministration

    Node $NodeName
    {
        foreach($AppPool in $AppPoolName) {
            xWebAppPool $AppPool
            {
                Name                           = $AppPool
                Ensure                         = 'Present'
                State                          = $state
                autoStart                      = $true
                idleTimeout                    = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 20).ToString()  
                restartPrivateMemoryLimit      = 700000
                logEventOnRecycle              = 'Time,Memory,PrivateMemory'
            }
        }
    }
}
Sample_xWebAppPool -NodeName "server" -state started -AppPoolName "AppPool1", "AppPool2", "AppPool3"
```

Make you AppPoolName parameter a string array and add a foreach to the xWebAppPool creation.